# What's the difference between a transformant and a recombinant dna? And how to differentiate them both?

Tags: biotechnology

I'm unable to understand the difference between the both. Would be really grateful if someone can explain it to me, in simple terms..

Comment: Can you show us the text that you find confusing? One normally thinks of a transformant as a clone of cells that have been transformed with some transferable DNA such as a plasmid (which could be a recombinant DNA element). But I think you could have found that with a simple google search.